# Python trace does not trace in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, trace

Trace does not trace functions defined in jupyter notebook - see attached screenshot below. Am I misusing the trace module and/or is there a better/correct way to get the chain of method execution or just a list of executed methods? Also, I'd like to avoid using notebook-specific solutions like `%%debug` cell magic if possible. [image]